# Persistent exchange password prompt after update to Redemption 5.22

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am working on an outlook vsto addin that uses redemption for some of the background outlook integration.

we recently updated to redemption version 5.22 and started getting reports from one of our customers, that they were getting persistent prompts for password on their exchange accounts while our addin was active.

i have reproduced this and there are a few factors needed to do so:

When setting up the exchange account in outlook, you have to check off the "remember my credentials" mark. if you don't select this, then you won't get prompted.

then you restart outlook and when it opens up you will get a prompt for the password, if you write the password again and press OK the prompt will close and immediately open again, asking for the password once more. this happens infinitely until you select cancel. and when you restart outlook it starts all over again.

i tried replacing the redemption.dll, redemption64.dll and interop.redemption.dll files in the installation, with the older ones we used (i am at the moment not aware which version they are) and that stopped the prompt from happening. reintroducing 5.22 also reintroduced the persistent prompt.

the only place in the code that could potentially cause a login prompt is a autodiscover call made with redemption, i tried removing that but the prompt still shows. so i don't think the problem is a coding issue.

are we doing something wrong with redemption?

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com - that problem was fixed in the post 5.22 builds.